# NextJs - React component methods get called twice per request

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm experimenting with NextJs Custom Server using Express. And i noticed that on every request, getInitialProps gets called twice. When trying to find out what the problem is i stumbled upon React.Strictmode being the reason for that since it calls certain class methods and constructor twice to help debug. When setting it to false, the getInitialProps method gets called three times. NextJs "pages" folder routing is disabled.
To be mentioned that render() gets called twice or three times too.

My server.js :

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
    
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const app = next({ dev });

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI)
.then(()=>{
  console.log('>Succesfully connected to the database');

  
  app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.listen(3000, (req, res) =>{
      console.log('>Listening on port 3000');
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res)=>{
      app.render(req, res, '/index', {something:true});
    })
    
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  })

})
.catch(e=>{
  console.log('<!>Error connecting to database: \n' + e);
});
```

and my GetInitialProps:

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx){
    console.log({...ctx.query});
    console.log('once');
    return {props:{...ctx.query}};
  }
```

Console when Strictmode on:

```
{ something: true }
once
{ something: true }
once
```

Console when Strictmode off:

```
{ something: true }
once
{ something: true }
once
{ something: true }
once
```

Comment: Is `app.render` inside `server.js` getting called multiple times when you access the page in the browser? The `server.get('*', ...)` handler is probably getting another match (for an asset or similar) when you access the page in the browser which re-renders the `index` page. Try changing `'*'` to `'/index'` and see if the duplicate call still happens.

Comment: I tried that, and the page displays blank, plain white. In network tab devtools every resource displays red

Comment: Yeah, you'll still have to handle all the assets in a different route that catches everything, after you defined the `/index` one.

Comment: Can you help me understand why is that necessary? I don't really know how to get under the hood as much as i would like

Comment: In addition to handling pages routes, the custom server also needs to handle all the assets it serves (JS, CSS, images, etc) which are served under the `/_next/` path.

Comment: Okay, got that. But my methods are still being called twice with strictmode on and three times with it off